# Display rows in refcursor without PRINT?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a stored procedure that looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_USERS(cursor_ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS

BEGIN

OPEN cursor_ FOR
      SELECT * FROM SYS.dba_users; 
END;
```

I test it like this:

```
var mycursor refcursor;
exec GET_USERS ( :mycursor );
print mycursor;
```

The problem is that `PRINT` displays it in `Script Output` tab instead of `Query Result` (with grid). It's easier for me to read from the grid.

Question 1: How can I test the stored procedure so that the result is displayed in `Query Result` with the grid?

Question 2: What's the difference between `F5` and the green arrow button when running a regular `SELECT` statement? When I highlight `SELECT * FROM SYS.dba_users;` and press `F5` I get the results in `Script Output`. If I press the green arrow button the results are displayed in `Query Result`.

Comment: You can create it as a function that returns a defined type, then query that directly in SQL (e.g. SELECT * FROM TABLE(myfunction))

Comment: Thanks. Would you have a link that explains how to create a function that returns a defined type?

Comment: Here you go: https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/databases/Oracle/PL-SQL/collection-types/return-table-from-function/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I test the stored procedure so that the result is displayed
>   in  Query Result with the grid

You don't...unless you write your procedure as a FUNCTION and you use it in a SELECT Query.

Like so:

```
create or replace function ref_expensive_emps return sys_refcursor
as
 c sys_refcursor;
begin
 open c for select * from employees order by salary desc fetch first 10 rows only;
 return c;
end  ref_expensive_emps;
/

select ref_expensive_emps() from dual;
```

[image]

Or execute that SELECT FROM DUAL as a script...

```
REF_EXPENSIVE_EMPS()
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                 EMAIL                     PHONE_NUMBER         HIRE_DATE           JOB_ID         SALARY COMMISSION_PCT MANAGER_ID DEPARTMENT_ID COLUMN1                                                                                                                         
----------- -------------------- ------------------------- ------------------------- -------------------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- -------------- ---------- ------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        100 Suppo0rt             King                      Suppo0rt                  515.123.4567         21-AUG-18  07.09.58 AD_PRES      49243.75                                      90                                                                                                                                 
        101 Neena                Kochhar                   NKOCHHAR                  515.123.5368         21-SEP-89  00.00.00 AD_VP        34888.29                       100            90                                                                                                                                 
        102 Lex                  De Haan                   LDEHAAN                   515.123.4569         13-JAN-93  00.00.00 AD_VP        34888.29                       100            90                                                                                                                                 
        145 John                 Russell                   JRUSSEL                   011.44.1344.429268   01-OCT-96  00.00.00 SA_MAN       28735.94             .4        100            80                                                                                                                                 
        146 Karen                Partners                  KPARTNER                  011.44.1344.467268   05-JAN-97  00.00.00 SA_MAN       27710.55             .3        100            80                                                                                                                                 
        201 Michael              Hartstein                 MHARTSTE                  515.123.5555         17-FEB-96  00.00.00 MK_MAN       26685.16                       100            20                                                                                                                                 
        108 Nancy                Greenberg                 NGREENBE                  515.124.4569         17-AUG-94  00.00.00 FI_MGR       24634.38                       101           100                                                                                                                                 
        205 Shelley              Higgins                   SHIGGINS                  515.123.8080         07-JUN-94  00.00.00 AC_MGR       24634.38                       101           110                                                                                                                                 
        147 Alberto              Errazuriz                 AERRAZUR                  011.44.1344.429278   10-MAR-97  00.00.00 SA_MAN       24634.38             .3        100            80                                                                                                                                 
        168 Lisa                 Ozer                      LOZER                     011.44.1343.929268   11-MAR-97  00.00.00 SA_REP       23608.99            .25        148            80                                                                                                                                 

10 rows selected.
```

> Question 2: What's the difference between F5 and the green arrow
>   button when running a regular SELECT statement?

Regular select statement: We run the query, do a single fetch, leave the dataset open, and print the results in the grid. As you scroll through the grid, we do more fetches as necessary. If you exhaust the resultset or close the grid, then the work on the db is finished.

F5/Execute as script: we run whatever is in the editor, or is highlighted, through our script engine (mimics SQL*Plus), and it gets printed in the script output panel. All rows are fetched.

If you execute your SP through the Code Editor, you can see your Refcursors in grids, but not the same grid as the SQL Worksheet.

[image]

Oh and with a refcursor, you only get to open/read it once...

Comment: I created the function. Is it possible to test it and display results in grid by just clicking the green arrow button or pressing `F5`?

Comment: i updated my answer, but yes @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf

Comment: I tried calling `select refcursor_function from dual;` with the green button and the `query result` tab returns just one column (column name `REFCURSOR_FUNCTION`) with all the contents.

Comment: look at the picture again, scroll to the right, double click the cell, get the pencil, click that - get the 'nice grid'...or run as a script, get regular query output

Comment: I saw it. I guess my question was how to show the results of a `select` statement inside a function or procedure in a grid without so many clicks

Comment: Use F5 or the print command...that's what we have today, there's like 4-5 ways to get your data out. the easiest is to use the Execute feature of the Code Editor for your function or procedure (open it from the tree)

Comment: You're right, but I'll be asking how to do all of this without clicking the mouse. In `SQL Server` I could create and test a stored procedure (to grid) with just the keyboard and `F5`. We have Toad Data Point and SQL Developer, and it doesn't seem I can't do this with either IDE.

Comment: Use F5 or the mouse, that's all I got for ya.

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf, SQL Server has always treated record sets with a bit more finesse than Oracle--it is so easy that it is common for SQL Server developers to return record sets from stored procedures instead of creating views. Oracle makes it a bit more challenging. What can I say? There is always something that is easier in one tool than another.